# how to get the login username while using django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django

I want to collect the login user's data while using Django. But i don't know how to locate the unique login username when i use django-registration-redux

I have tried to do this, here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from yigu.models import Gw, user_data
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
    Gw_list = Gw.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'cyshici': Gw_list}
    return render(request, 'yigu/base.html', context_dict)

def search(request):
    if 'gw' in request.GET:

        words_1 = request.GET['gw']
        result_list = Gw.objects.filter(field_1=words_1)
        result_list2 = user_data.objects.filter(word=words_1)
        result_list3 = user_data.objects.filter(user=User.username)
        # For basic search match and display content
        if result_list:
            context_dict = {'result_list': result_list}
            words = Gw.objects.get(field_1=words_1)
            words.views = words.views + 1
            words.save()

            # For words_information Model
            if result_list2 & result_list3:
                words2 = user_data.objects.get(word=words_1)
                words2.click_times = words2.click_times + 1
                words2.save()

            else:
                words2 = user_data(user=User.username, word=words_1, click_times=words.views)
                words2.save()

            return render(request, 'yigu/search.html', context_dict)
```

here's my models.py:

```
class user_data(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    click_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('click_times',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

But the all the username is something like this `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>`

Could anyone give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

User models of using Redux:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

And add an OneToOneField to user_data:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```